# Permalink coming from the Front Matter

Tags: ruby, config, jekyll, permalinks

I'm working in Jekyll, and I want to customize the permalink of my posts, so I add this line in `config.yml`:

```
permalink: /:category/:title/
```

The `category` is the category of the post and `title` is its name as `.md` file. But suppose I want to get info from the from matter of the post: imagine the front matter of `file.md` is

```
---
title: my_title
lang: en
---
```

Now I want to get this title (`my_title`, not `file`) and this lang, so that I gent `.../en/my_title.md`. So in `config.yml` I should have

```
permalink: /page.lang/page.title/
```

Obviously that does not work because I'm mixing different languages. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables in the front matter.

But you can put your post in an `en/` folder and have a default permalink for posts like `:path/:title`.